# Return first row within CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I have a case statement within a select returning many values, but I only want the first value since I'm doing a Count.

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
ATM.TicketID
,COUNT(CASE WHEN ((ATM.PriorityID='E' OR ATM.PriorityID='U') AND 
MAX(ATQ.QuestionID) THEN 1 END)) AS [A]
.....
```

For each 'E' and 'U' value, there are many QuestionID's (joined from another table).  But I only need one QuestionID for each E or U.

I'm having difficulty with nested aggregates.

Comment: you  can't time travel in a query. `max()` value won't be known until all rows have been scanned, so it can't be used WHILE you're scanning the rows.

Comment: I don't need to necessarily use MAX, I just need to select one of the many QuestionID's

Answer (score 0):

Move the PriorityID to a where clause

```
SELECT   
ATM.TicketID, ATM.PriorityID, MAX(ATQ.QuestionID)
FROM ATM
    INNER JOIN ATQ ON {some criteria}
WHERE ATM.PriorityID = 'E'OR ATM.PriorityID = 'U'
GROUP BY ATM.TicketID, ATM.PriorityID
```